# Partial derivative of metric tensor help

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, tensors, curvature

This may be a dumb question, but I am relatively new to Tensor Calculus and I was wondering what this partial derivative of the metric tensor would turn out to be:

$\frac {\partial g_{µv}}{\partial x^µ} $

where $g_{µv}$ is the metric tensor

I have not seen any form of the metric tensor like $g_µ$, so would this expression exist or is there an identity or property that defines what this expression is?

Comment: A comment beside say answer below: $g_{\mu}$ would not be a metric tensor anymore, just a vector.

Comment: The "vector" defined by $v_\nu = \partial_\mu g_{\mu \nu}$ depends on the coordinates in which you compute it, so any significance of this quantity would be specifically tied to the coordinates $x^\mu$. For example, we can always make it vanish at any point by choosing normal coordinates, regardless of the metric.

Answer (score 4):

Consider $\mu$ to be an index that usually runs from $0$ to $3$. In particular, in general relativity, the four-vector $x^{\mu}$ denotes the row vector with components:

$$x^{\mu} = (x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3) = (ct, x, y, z)$$

Where $c$ is the speed of light, usually taken in Planck units to $c = 1$.

Hence this is a vector.

On the other side, the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ is a "matrix" (or better: it can be represented as a matrix) which turns out to be a $4\times 4$ matrix, since the $\nu$ index runs itself from $0$ to $3$.

In order to understand what is that derivative, let's take a simple trivial and probably non existent (in terms of physics) metric tensor of the form

$$
g_{\mu\nu} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & x^2 & 0 \\
0 & xy & xy & 0 \\
x^2 & xy & xy & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now when we want to compute a derivative $\frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}}$, what we really want is the derivative of the $\mu\nu$ component of the tensor with respect to the $\mu$ index.

When using Einstein convention, when an index is repeated, then a hidden sum over all the indices exists. In this way the derivative you wrote represents

$$ \frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}} =  \frac{\partial g_{0\nu}}{\partial x^{0}} +  \frac{\partial g_{1\nu}}{\partial x^{1}}+  \frac{\partial g_{2\nu}}{\partial x^{2}} +  \frac{\partial g_{3\nu}}{\partial x^{3}}$$

But this also means

$$ \frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}} =  \frac{\partial g_{0\nu}}{\partial t} +  \frac{\partial g_{1\nu}}{\partial x}+  \frac{\partial g_{2\nu}}{\partial y} +  \frac{\partial g_{3\nu}}{\partial z}$$

Now you see that we have a metric tensor whose components (16 in total) are declared by the index $\nu$. Since the metric tensor is ALWAYS symmetric, what are the nonzero components here? They are:

$$g_{03},\ g_{11},\ g_{12},\ g_{20},\ g_{21},\ g_{22},\ g_{33}$$

p.s. $\mu$ stands for the ROW and $\nu$ stands for the COLUMN, hence the element $g_{02}$ is, for example, the $x^2$ in the first row.

According to what component we are serving, we can take the derivative.

For example there is no term in the tensor which depends upon both $t$ and $z$ hence those derivatives will be identically zero.

The only derivatives that exist are the ones which involve the above written nonzero elements of the tensor, with respect to $x$ and $y$.

Let take the above representation again:

$$ \frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}} =  \frac{\partial g_{0\nu}}{\partial t} +  \frac{\partial g_{1\nu}}{\partial x}+  \frac{\partial g_{2\nu}}{\partial y} +  \frac{\partial g_{3\nu}}{\partial z}$$

As we noticed, $z$ and $t$ derivatives are zero, hence:

$$ \frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}} =  \frac{\partial g_{1\nu}}{\partial x}+  \frac{\partial g_{2\nu}}{\partial y} $$

Now what remains? The component $g_{1\nu}$ is nonzero only for $\nu = 1$ and $2$. The components are identical and their derivative is (with respect to $x$) just $y$ as you can see.

On the other side, when we deal with $g_{2\nu}$ the only nonzero components happen for $\nu = 0, 1, 2$ but $g_{20}$ does not depend on $y$ hence the derivative will be zero.

And so on.

I hope you more or less got the point!

**$g_{\mu}$**

This expression would represent a vector with $4$ components, in accordance with what I wrote above.

The derivative in this case would be just the derivative of the $\mu$ component of $g$, with respect to the $\mu$ component of the coordinates vector. I never saw such a notation, and it would be uncomfortable but in layman's terms it would be

$$\frac{\partial g_{\mu}}{\partial x^{\mu}} = \frac{\partial g_{0}}{\partial t} +  \frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial x}+  \frac{\partial g_{2}}{\partial y} +  \frac{\partial g_{3}}{\partial z}$$

This would however be quite incorrect to write since it's better to use different index, like for example

$$\frac{\partial g_{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}}$$